# How to center HTML element horizontally in Kramdown Markdown?

Tags: html, css, markdown, kramdown

I have an HTML element in my markdown file (kramdown), which is basically just two columns. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/KidPiano/pen/NWWzLjE.

```
<div style="-webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; -webkit-column-rule: 1px dotted #e0e0e0; -moz-column-rule: 1px dotted #e0e0e0; column-rule: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;">

<div style="display:inline-block">
<h2 style="text-align:center">Good</h2>
<pre><code class="language-c">int foo (void)    
{
    int i;
}
</code></pre>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block">
<h2 style="text-align:center">Bad</h2>
<pre><code class="language-c">int foo (void) {
    int i;
}  
<span style="background-color:cyan">test</span>
</code></pre>
</div>

</div>
```

Is there any way to horizontally center these columns in the middle of the page?

Edit: answered below - don't use column count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div style="text-align:center;">

  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Good</h2>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-c">
          int foo (void)    
          {
          int i;
          }
        </code>
    </pre>
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Bad</h2>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-c">
        int foo (void) 
        {
        int i;
        }  
        <span style="background-color:cyan">test</span>
       </code>
   </pre>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The columns are centered now, but not aligned horizontally. I'll see if I can play around with it a bit more.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out thanks. I don't know why I used column-count.